# In Angular4 whenever I am adding form tag getting No Provider for ControlContainer error

Tags: forms, angular-cli, angular-reactive-forms

At first I have added the ReactiveFormModule in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NewproducComponent } from './comp/newproduc/newproduc.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './comp/products/products.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './comp/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { MenubarComponent } from './comp/menubar/menubar.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path : '' , component : ProductsComponent},
  { path : 'newproduct' , component : NewproducComponent}
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewproducComponent,
    ProductsComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    MenubarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
 }
```

the app.component.html contanis

```
<app-menubar></app-menubar>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

the newproduc.component.html contains

```
<div id="main-body">
  <div class="main-body-header">
            <span>New Product</span>
            <button type="button">Close</button>
            <button type="button">Save</button>
  </div>

  <div class="main-body-component">
    <div class="container">
       <form>

        </form>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

when adding this form tag i am getting the following error

[Error in browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enljv.png)

Whenever, I remove the form tag the error removes. I am not sure where i made the error. Please help me in solving the issue. I have stacked for last 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
```

Because you are importing `ReactiveFormsModule`, the `<form>` tag must have a `formGroup`.